# Set a script to run on a schedule?

Tags: scheduled-tasks

How can I set a PHP script to run on a schedule? I don't have full control over the server as I am using a hosting company, I have a PLESK administration for the hosting though.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have shell access?  If so, you can use cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe PLESK has a **crontab** area underneath each domain.

[image]

Alternatively, if you have shell access, here's a good tutorial on [editing your crontab from the command-line](http://www.adminschoice.com/docs/crontab.htm).

Comment: Thanks, I have a section that looks just like the image you posted but the crontab button is missing, the icons are slightly different so I don't know if its because it is a different version or if its just disabled, I'll contact my host. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

crontab. video tutorial here:

http://www.webhostingresourcekit.com/flash/plesk-8-linux/plesk8linux_crontab.html

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is called a cron job: an automated task that can execute a http request on your server.

Since you're hosted, it's impossible to manually set up a cron job to run. However, many web hosts offer online tools for creating cron jobs through their control panel (cpanel, plesk, etc).

If that isn't an option, there are some paid and SOME free cron services you might be able to find if you poke around long enough.